# For all positive real numbers $x$ and $y$, prove or disprove $⌈x ⋅ y⌉ ≤ ⌈x⌉ ⋅ ⌈y⌉$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So far I have written:

$$x = m + r, m \in \mathbb{Z} \ \text{and} \  0 \leq r < 1
$$

$$y = l + s, l \in \mathbb{Z} \ \text{and} \ 0 \leq s < 1$$

$$\lceil x\cdot y \rceil = \lceil (m+r)(l+s) \rceil = \lceil ml+ms+rl+rs \rceil$$

$$\lceil x \rceil \cdot \lceil y \rceil = m\cdot l$$

I can't conclude on these findings.

Comment: Why don't you just do case analysis? one integral, niehter integral? (both integral is trivial)

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Ok everything is supposed to be as the title is... Please disregard any mistake I have made...

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction! @Ahmed S. Attaalla

Comment: You can use two useful properties:

$
\lceil a \rceil \leq \lceil b \rceil \text{ if } a \leq b
$
and if $0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2$ and $0 \leq y_1 \leq y_2$, then $x_1y_1 \leq x_2y_2$.

Comment: What you did will work fo floor functions.  For ceiling function use instead: $\lceil x \rceil = x+r $  then you get $ \lceil x \rceil \lceil y\rceil = xy + ry+x+s+rs \ge xy$

Comment: **Exact dupe** of [How to prove that the $\lceil xy \rceil \le \lceil x \rceil \lceil y \rceil$ for positive real numbers $x, y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212114/how-to-prove-that-the-lceil-xy-rceil-le-lceil-x-rceil-lceil-y-rceil-for)

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

If $n$ is an integer, then $\lceil z\rceil\le n\iff z\le n.$

$\lceil x\rceil\cdot\lceil y\rceil$ is an integer.

$x\le\lceil x\rceil.$

Answer (score 0):

$\lceil x\rceil \ge x \ge 0$ and $\lceil y\rceil \ge y \ge 0$

so $\lceil x \rceil \lceil y\rceil \ge xy$.

$ \lceil x \rceil \lceil y\rceil$ is an integer that is at least as large as $xy $.  The least such integer is $\lceil xy\rceil $.  So $ \lceil x \rceil \lceil y\rceil \ge  \lceil x  y\rceil$ .

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing floor with ceiling.

Let $x = m-r $ and $y=n-s $. So $m,n $ are *larger* not smaller than $x,n$.

$(m-r)(n-s)\le mn $ so $[(m-r)(n-s)]\le[mn] $.

And $mn $ is an integer so $[mn]=mn$.

Therefore: $[x][y]=mn $  and $[xy]=[(m-r)(n-s)]\le [mn]=mn=[x][y]$